# Blog excerpt in Django

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am building a blog application in Django and when I display all the blogs I want to display a small blog excerpt with each entry. Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

> One way to do that would be to make an extra field and store a fixed number of words for 
>   each blog entry, let's say 20 words. But then that would be storing redundant information 
>   in the database. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Depending on if you want the excerpt to be editable or not determines the correct answer.  Could do it simply with a def excerpt(self) and return the body chopped to a certain string length and then sanitize the html if any.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest you use the [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) template filter.

Template example:

```
<ul>
{% for blogpost in blogposts %}
    <li><b>{{blogpost.title}}</b>: {{blogpost.content|truncatewords:10}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If the blog content is stored as HTML, use `truncatewords_html` to ensure that open tags are closed after the truncation point (or combine with `striptags` to remove html tags).

If you want to truncate on characters (not words), you can use `slice`:

```
{{blogpost.content|slice:":10"}}
```

(outputs first 10 characters).

If content is stored as HTML, combine with `striptags` to avoid open tags problems: `{{blogpost.content|striptags|slice:":10"}}`

Comment: This will truncate the words to a specific length... However is there anything if I want to truncate to a specific number of characters because words can be longer in length and I don't want my box to be becoming too big

Comment: If you do decide to add a summary field in your blog model, you can fallback to the truncatewords if the summary is blank (using if and else tags in template). But generally the truncate template tag/filter is the popular method for doing this.

Comment: @Sachin: Updated answer w/ truncate to character count.

Comment: `striptags` saved my day. Thanks for this advice!

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.4 and later, there's a [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter that will truncate a string to a specific length and terminate it with `...`.  It actually truncates it to the specific length minus 3, and the last 3 characters become the `...`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related..

I just provided an answer to this question: [Django strip_tags template filter add space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139455/django-strip-tags-template-filter-add-space/) that may help others when making excerpts that contain HTML tags and short content in <p> tags.

Helps convert this..

```
"<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>"
```

to this..

```
'This is a paragraph. This is another paragraph.'
```

instead of this..

```
'This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph.'
```