# Django strip_tags template filter add space

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I use djangos template filter [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags). Example:

```
>>> from django.utils.html import strip_tags
>>> strip_tags("<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>")
'This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph.'
```

What is the best way to add a space character between the paragraphs, so that I get this string instead:

```
'This is a paragraph. This is another paragraph.'
```

Edit:

One idea I have is to write a custom template filter that replaces all `</p>` tags with `[space]</p>` before the `striptags` filter is used. But is that a clean and robust solution?

Comment: Can you add a space or enter in the template? Like `"...</p>\n<p>..."`

Answer (score 3):

yes, it seems like a clean solution to me.  I had a similar issue when trying to create an excerpt for some articles in a WagTail (built on Django) application.  I was using this syntax in my template..

```
{{ page.body|striptags|truncatewords:50 }}
```

.. and getting the same issue you described. Here is an implementation I came up - hopefully useful for other Django / WagTail developers as well.

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.html import strip_spaces_between_tags, strip_tags
from django.utils.text import Truncator

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='excerpt')
def excerpt_with_ptag_spacing(value, arg):

    try:
        limit = int(arg)
    except ValueError:
        return 'Invalid literal for int().'

    # remove spaces between tags
    value = strip_spaces_between_tags(value)

    # add space before each P end tag (</p>)
    value = value.replace("</p>"," </p>")

    # strip HTML tags
    value = strip_tags(value)

    # other usage: return Truncator(value).words(length, html=True, truncate=' see more')
    return Truncator(value).words(limit)
```

and you use it like this..

```
{{ page.body|excerpt:50 }}
```